# The number of variables that parametrize a particular curve or surface.

Tags: differential-geometry

It is possible to parametrize a line in $\Bbb{R^n}$ using one variable. For example, $(t,2t)$ is a line in $\Bbb{R^2}$ for $t\in\Bbb{R}$.

However, it is also possible to parametrize it using two variables. The same line in $\Bbb{R^2}$ can also be written as $(t+k,2(t+k))$ for $t,k\in\Bbb{R}$.

Shouldn't the number of variables parametrizing a surface or a curve be constant? You may argue that $t+k$ is essentially one variable. However, what is the "rule" or "theorem" on this: the number of variables parametrizing a curve/surface?

Comment: You mean parametrizing a **line** in $\Bbb R^n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A parametrization of an object (such as a line or a plane) in $\mathbb{R}^n$ usually refers to an *injective* (i.e., *one-to-one*) function $\phi$ from $\mathbb{R}^k$ (or a subset of $\mathbb{R}^k$) to $\mathbb{R}^n$ that is a *bijection* onto its image (usually that bijection is in fact a homeomorphism or diffeomorphism, depending on the context).

Your first example is the function $\phi_1: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ given by $\phi_1(t) = (t, 2t)$. Crucially, $\phi_1$ is a *bijection* from $\mathbb{R}$ onto its image, which is a line in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Your second example is the function $\phi_2: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ given by $\phi_2(t, k) = (t + k, 2(t+k))$. Although $\phi_2$ is a surjective function onto the line in question, it's not injective since multiple points in the domain map to the same point in the image (e.g., $\phi_2(0,1) = \phi_2(1,0) = (1,2)$). This means it's not a "parametrization" in the usual sense. You should think that because $\phi_2$ is not injective, one of the two variables is "redundant."

Essentially, subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ that can be (locally) parametrized in the above sense are called *manifolds*. Examples of manifolds are lines, planes, and more curvy objects like spheres. There may be many different ways to parametrize a manifold, but, as you suspected, every parametrization must always have the same number of variables $k$. $k$ is called the *dimension* of the manifold. For example, a line has dimension 1 (as we saw above, using more than one variable to try to parametrize a line introduces a redundancy). Planes and spheres in $\mathbb{R}^3$ both have dimension 2.